# JavaBeans - Sorting by alphabetical

Tags: java, html, list, sorting, alphabetical

So I'm doing a small person project but I have ran into issues. I would like the the information to load alphabetically when the page loads but I don't know how to do it, any suggestions? Thanks. This has been updated from what it was previously.

```
<%@page import="campus.system.userdatamodel.Users"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <%@include file="/WEB-INF/jspf/loadDataModelSegment.jspf" %>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>List of Users</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Users</h1>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name</td>
                    <td>Delete</td>
                </tr>
                    <% 
                        Integer index;
                        index = 0;
                        for(Users currUser : mySystemUsers.getUserList())
                        {
                            out.println("<tr>");
                            out.println("<td>");
                            out.println(currUser.getName());
                            out.println("</td>");

                            out.println("<td>");

                    %>
                  <form method="post" action="ProcessUserServlet">
                    <input type="image" name="action" value="DELETE" src="/CampusSystemWebGUI/image/Delete.png" title="Delete User">
                    <input hidden="true" name="index" value=
                           <% 
                               out.println("\"" + index.toString() + "\""); 
                           %> 
                           >
                    </form>
                    <%
                        index++;
                        out.println("</td>");

                        out.println("</tr>");

                    }
                    %>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="/CampusSystemWebGUI">Main Menu</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to sort the list by a field before adding them to the page?

Comment: I would like them to appear in alphabetical order when the page loads

Answer (score 0):

You can add the names in natural order this way.

```
    List<String> names = mySystemUsers.getUserList().stream()
            .map(u -> u.getName())
            .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (String name: names) {
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println(name);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
```

As it appears you have configured Java 5, you can try this instead.

```
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Users user:  mySystemUsers.getUserList()) {
        names.add(user.getName());
    }
    Collections.sort(names);
    for (String name: names) {
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println(name);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
```

Note: a single user should really have a class called `User` not `Users`

Note: this requires Java 8

Comment: I do not understand how to add this.

Comment: @NeonUniverse replace the code you have in `<%` to `%>`

Comment: Ive updated my code since I attempting to add it and it wont work it throws alot of errors? any more suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you read the errors.  They might be trying to tell you something.  Which version of Java do you have?

Comment: Hi im using java 8, Ive read through the errors but I do no understand them, my java knowledge is quite basic.

Comment: @NeonUniverse what do the errors say? Perhaps if you post them we can tell you what they mean.

Comment: It says void Type isnt allowed here another one says unreported execption IOException;must be caught or declared to be thrown and finally for-each not applicable to expression type required: array or java.lang.lterable found: void

Comment: @NeonUniverse can you try the code from my updated answer?

Comment: The code will go in without any errors but when i load the java page on a browser it causes it to crash

Comment: @NeonUniverse What crashes?  What error do you get?

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

Comment: PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 27 in the jsp file: /viewSystemUsers.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
'try' without 'catch' or 'finally'

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
illegal start of type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
illegal start of type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
';' expected

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
<identifier> expected

Comment: PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
<identifier> expected

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: As the error message says, you need to enable to source from Java 8. It is current set for Java 1.5.

Comment: @NeonUniverse I have updated my answer as you appear to have Java 1.5 configured.

Comment: It doesnt work, the List gives a yellows line at the bottom and it says redundant type arguments in new expression(use diamon operator instread).

Comment: @NeonUniverse this is a warning for Java 7+ but is required for Java 1.5 which is why you can't remove it.

Comment: Fair enough thanks for the help with what you have done